# What is the word for being inured to loss of biological diversity?

Tags: biodiversity

In the title.  The word has been coined relatively recently for the phenomenon of getting used to loss of diversity because of the gradual rate it happens at.  For example, not finding it strange that there are far fewer invertebrates around now than there were 30 years ago - car windscreens in the summer were covered in dead insects, whereas now that rarely happens.  Both time points are noticeably distinct in biological richness, but we quickly get used to the state of things now.  I can't find it on Google!

Comment: biocide conditioning/acculturation/habituation. Naturacidal ambivalence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a language question, rather than a question about a problem in biology.

Comment: @David It's a question about terminology within ecology. I'd say that fits in Biology

Comment: Actually this is a question about the word used to describe a psychological response to a biological phenomenon.  I have to agree that this doesn't seem to belong here — maybe [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/)? —— Please take the time to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 